# When is a $2$-Calabi–Yau triangulated category the cluster category of a QP?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, cluster-algebras

Keller–Reiten's main theorem in *[Acyclic Calabi–Yau categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610594)* implies that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a $2$-Calabi–Yau (algebraic) triangulated category admitting a cluster-tilting object $T$ such that the quiver $Q$ of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(T)$ is acyclic, then $\mathcal{C}$ is triangle-equivalent to the cluster category $\mathcal{C}_Q$.

In general, the endomorphism algebras of cluster-tilting objects in $\mathcal{C}_Q$ do not have acyclic quivers, but their endomorphism algebras are given by the Jacobian algebra of a quiver with potential (QP) $(Q',W)$ mutation equivalent to the QP $(Q,0)$.

Not all quivers with potential are mutation equivalent to acyclic ones, but for any QP $(Q,W)$ with finite-dimensional Jacobian algebra, Amiot introduces a cluster category $\mathcal{C}_{(Q,W)}$ in section 3 of *[Cluster categories for algebras of global dimension 2 and quivers with potential](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1035)*. This category admits a cluster-tilting object $T$ with endomorphism algebra isomorphic to the Jacobian algebra of $(Q,W)$.

My question is the following:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a $2$-Calabi–Yau algebraic triangulated category, and $T$ is a cluster-tilting object of $\mathcal{C}$ with finite-dimensional endomorphism algebra isomorphic to the Jacobian algebra of a QP $(Q,W)$, is $\mathcal{C}$ equivalent to $\mathcal{C}_{(Q,W)}$?

If $Q$ is acyclic (so $W=0$), then this is Keller–Reiten's result, and the answer is also yes if $(Q,W)$ is mutation equivalent to $(Q',0)$ for $Q'$ acyclic (in which case $\mathcal{C}_{(Q,W)}\simeq\mathcal{C}_{Q'}$). I thought I had read somewhere that the answer is always yes, but I can't seem to find this again now – maybe I am misremembering.

**Update:** The thing I was half remembering is Lemma 4.5 in Keller–Reiten. In this setting, this says that if I have a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{(Q,W)}$ that takes $T$ to a cluster-tilting object $T'\in\mathcal{C}_{(Q,W)}$ such that $\operatorname{End}(T')$ is the Jacobian algebra of $(Q,W)$, and $F$ induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(T)\to\operatorname{End}(T')$, then $F$ is an equivalence. So a positive answer to my question would be implied by the existence of such a functor, but this existence is not a priori obvious, at least to me.